# NAS recovery via disk removal

Tags: linux, data-recovery, raid, software-raid, nas

I have a couple cheaper Lenovo IX2 2-disk NAS devices.  First of all, there is NO hardware failure, including disk.  I had a power jolt and one IX2 was on a dead UPS and dropped and came back a couple times, which was enough to corrupt the IX Linux OS.  Because this is a NAS that is copying it's opt read only at boot every time and already was a super pain just to edit running config or install optware etc., I have no issue simply rebuilding it from an old config.

ISSUE Symptoms:
Much running config seems lost, web GUI indicates a factory reset/restore is needed.

HOWEVER - ONCE I MANUALLY MOUNTED THE RAID POOL using the other working IX2 as a "template" of things to look at, the good news is ALL USER DATA IS IN TACT AND NO RAID ERRORS EXIST.  (This is RAID0, so I would be totally SOL if there were, I fully realize that).

Because the data IS all there is the only reason I am working this hard (but it really shouldn't be).

The key here is some user data, but then I had a 2tb iSCSI volume on this IX, being used 100% for VMware.  This iSCSI volume file is also in tact.  This, being my datastore is really what I am after.

WORK ALREADY COMPLETED:
I have unboxed a brand new 4tb WD USB3 drive (albeit only USB2 on the IX2), plugged it in, and used mkfs to reformat the default partition as EXT4.  I then mounted it as /dev/usb and began this command, roughly 20 hrs ago already:

```
rsync -axHAWXS --numeric-ids --progress /mnt/pools/A/A0/ /mnt/usb
```

Yes, I now see that because I initially tried the newer info:progress2 and it did not work, that I merely quickly edited the cmd and forgot to add the friggin -P for partial.  That is one question, I would really like to kill this and restart it, can I still use --append having forgotten to use --partial originally?  How can I force a continue and AVOID losing this 20+hrs if I need to restart now?  (This is an optional portion of my question)

I ran the rsync specifically for the progress and checksums and restart ability fully knowing it was much slower than standard cp - but this IX2 always sucked but I could push reads over the 100mbit to 50-65MB/s via iSCSI, yet this rsync is averaging ~10MB on the iSCSI 2tb file.  It's absurd and it is estimating 3 more days.

GOAL:
My ultimate goal (and question here) is how to abandon this old IX2 hardware and move the disks and get them mounted on newer PC running a newer Linux distro at full SATA3 & USB3 in hours not days.

---

## ADDITIONAL DETAILS:

---

### Command output for fdisk -l:

---

```
root@ix2b:/mnt/usb/iSCSI# fdisk -l

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x6fcb5480

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2fbbf4b0

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT

Disk /dev/md0: 21.5 GB, 21474762752 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 5242862 cylinders, total 41942896 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md0 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md1: 3957.8 GB, 3957777760256 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 966254336 cylinders, total 7730034688 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 1048576 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
Note: sector size is 4096 (not 512)

Disk /dev/sdc: 4000.8 GB, 4000752599040 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60799 cylinders, total 976746240 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xdb4bf07b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1             256   976746239  3906983936    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
root@ix2b:/mnt/usb/iSCSI#
```

---

### Command output for parted:

---

```
Model: WDC WD20EFRX-68AX9N0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      33.6MB  21.5GB  21.5GB               primary
 2      21.5GB  2000GB  1979GB               primary


Model: WDC WD20EFRX-68AX9N0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      33.6MB  21.5GB  21.5GB               primary
 2      21.5GB  2000GB  1979GB               primary


Model: WD My Book 1230 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  4001GB  4001GB  primary


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/b9b358d_vg-lv3707c1c1: 3958GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  3958GB  3958GB  ext4


Error: /dev/mtdblock0: unrecognised disk label

Error: /dev/mtdblock1: unrecognised disk label

Error: /dev/mtdblock2: unrecognised disk label

Error: /dev/mtdblock3: unrecognised disk label

Error: /dev/md0: unrecognised disk label

Error: /dev/md1: unrecognised disk label
```

---

### Command output for uname:

---

```
root@ix2b:/mnt/usb/iSCSI# uname -a
Linux ix2b 2.6.31.8 Tue Aug 30 10:28:13 EDT 2016 v0.0.9 Tue Aug 30 10:28:13 EDT 2016 armv5tel GNU/Linux
```

---

### Command output for lsblk:

---

```
root@ix2b:/mnt/usb/iSCSI# lsblk /dev/sd[bc] -o NAME,SIZE,TYPE,MAJ:MIN
NAME                                 SIZE TYPE  MAJ:MIN
sdb                                  1.8T disk    8:16
|-sdb1                                20G part    8:17
| `-md0                               20G raid1   9:0
`-sdb2                               1.8T part    8:18
  `-md1                              3.6T raid0   9:1
    `-b9b358d_vg-lv3707c1c1 (dm-0)   3.6T lvm   253:0
sdc                                  3.7T disk    8:32
`-sdc1                               1.7T part    8:33
```

Answer (score 1):

I apparently posted this on the wrong S.O. site - the askubuntu apparently has dealt much more with this issue and I found some references to study.

So I will post an initial answer but I am not convinced as to whether there is a lot more to this - if there is, please comment here to help others!

1. Boot LiveCD on newer hardware with 2 SATA drives plugged into ports 0 & 1 and new data target drive attached via SATA or USB3
2. Install mdadm:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mdadm
   ```
3. Scan all drives for RAID volumes:

   ```
   sudo mdadm -Q /dev/sd[a-f][1-9]
   ```
4. Attempt to scan and assemble and open in nautilus:

   ```
   sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
   ```
5. CP/Rsync/TAR/etc your data off the RAID volume to new data target

   EDIT: So far the answer I posted above was correct, but this NAS set up the disks/RAID LVM like this:

   root@ubuntu:~# sudo lsblk -f
   NAME    FSTYPE    LABEL        UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
   sdb
   ├─sdb2  linux_rai ix2b:1       0b3fca64-f33a-21cc-45dc-6353be71366e
   │ └─md1 LVM2_memb              HgGqsx-nrcC-MF1f-tWYK-Iv3w-g24n-MylTHy 
   └─sdb1  linux_rai ix2-dl-113:0 70d23f10-3d2b-9d15-4af5-7c4e11dda669
   └─md0
   sdc
   ├─sdc2  linux_rai ix2b:1       0b3fca64-f33a-21cc-45dc-6353be71366e
   │ └─md1 LVM2_memb              HgGqsx-nrcC-MF1f-tWYK-Iv3w-g24n-MylTHy 
   └─sdc1  linux_rai ix2-dl-113:0 70d23f10-3d2b-9d15-4af5-7c4e11dda669
   └─md0
   sda
   ├─sda2
   ├─sda5  swap                   d7fa7f10-c009-435c-8435-e0b4556a235b   [SWAP]
   └─sda1  ext4                   5e18f5b8-ff52-4f82-8a2a-24d687eb8413   /

EDIT:  I have pieced together the remainder of the steps and will be writing them up to add here and also build a guide to post.  I have all the RAID volumes mounted in a USB3/SATA virtual machine which has proved to work great and is a nice spin on the approach others seem to take trying to recover NAS drives.  I have them mounted via SATA3-->USB3 converters tested in the VM at approx 120-150MB/sec seq x 2 for the stripe so a TON faster than leaving them in the NAS!  Stay tuned!